# Intermittent, but frequent touchpad problem: right-click menu keeps popping up

Tags: touchpad, cinnamon

Lately I have developed a problem with my laptop (HP g7,Trusty/ Cinnamon amd64 install, current with updates): when left clicking, particularly on the scrollbar, the right-click menu suddenly appears, creating the hazard of inadvertantly making a selection from the menu while attempting to scroll down the window being displayed. I can release the leftclick button over a blank area and re-select, usually (but not always) regaining left-click control immediately, but of course I'd like to fix this issue and have no idea why it occurs in the first place. Any ideas? Is anyone else having this problem?

TIA

CS

Answer (score 1):

I had been the same problem. Looking around I found [a info](http://who-t.blogspot.de/2013/12/lenovo-t440-touchpad-button.html) which helps me to solve the problem. I changed the the SoftButtonAreas as recommended and the problem disappears.

Regards Rainer